# OpenVPN clinet cannot connect after re install OpenVPN server

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I was forced to re-install the Ubuntu openvpn server I have many users who were connected to the server.

Before reinstall OS and installing the new OpenVPN I copy all the OpenVPN folders from etc and restored to new ubuntu folder.
but old users cannot connect to the OpenVPN server but when I create a new user it can register!

Does anybody have the same issue that can help me?

Thank You

Comment: I'm not familiar with the OpenVPN server setup, but if it follows standard Linux / POSIX practice, it won't keep user data in `/etc`. The `/etc` directory is for configuration, not for variable data. Most likely, it keeps user data below `/var/lib`, e.g. in `/var/lib/openvpn`.

Comment: I can see users under /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/pki/issued
my clients just connect by crt and key file in their local computer and they don't have usernames and passwords.

I can see my clients trying to connect to OpenVPN server when I do tcpdump on port 1194 but I get this error on syslog
openvpn[766]: tls-crypt unwrap error: packet authentication failed

Comment: Did you make sure ownership and permissions on all files were preserved when they were copied over?

Comment: It will be helpful to add some logging output, as there is very little information to go on now.

Comment: all the sub files and folders under /etc/openvpn/server have 0755 permission